# Trigger error microsoft sql server studio 2018

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSafeBatch 
   ON  ClientService 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Closed != OLD.Closed THEN
        UPDATE SafeBatch SET SafeBatch.TotalVisa=SafeBatch.TotalVisa+ClientService.TotalVisa,
                     SafeBatch.TotalCash=SafeBatch.TotalCash+ClientService.TotalCash,
                     SafeBatch.Total=SafeBatch.Total+ClientService.Total,
        WHERE SafeBatch.Id=ClientService.SafeBatchId

    END
GO
```

Comment: This looks nothing like SQL Server trigger syntax, so your question does not make sense.  You should start with the documentation.

Comment: i want to make atrigger that when  update table ClientService field Closed then update SafeBatch columns with specific operations

Comment: Could you tell us the error message that you are having?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSafeBatchAbdallah 
   ON  ClientService 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    --IF NEW.Closed != OLD.Closed THEN

        UPDATE SafeBatch SET TotalVisa+=inserted.TotalVisa,
                     TotalCash+=inserted.TotalCash,
                     Total+=inserted.Total
                      FROM inserted
        WHERE SafeBatch.Id=inserted.SafeBatchId and inserted.Closed=1

END
GO
```